# How cani fix the send_keys Attribute Error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I am trying to write a search on the google search bar.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\HP\\PycharmProjects\\SeleniumTest1\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("LinkedIn login")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("LinkedIn Login").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("enter your username")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("enter your password")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
```

This is the error I keep getting from the console

```
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("LinkedIn login")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This implies that it couldn't find any element by name ```q```.  Check if ```driver.find_element_by_name("q")``` returns None.

Comment: @Prophet  I stand corrected.

Comment: @ewong In case `that it couldn't find any element by name q` it would throw `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element`

Comment: @Prophet Where do you see the driver issue that you mention? I don't see any difference between this instantiation vs what's in the Selenium docs. I agree that something strange is going on and may be a setup/config issue but I don't see what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current selenium version uses `find_element()` to get elements. Try the code below. Change the by attribute to the one you are searching with

```
driver.find_element(by="name", value = "q").send_keys("LinkedIn login")
```

Comment: How is this code (practically) any different than the code OP is already using? They both search for the element using name="q". There's no reason to believe the result here is going to be any different than what OP already got, is there?

Comment: @Prophet "Wrong!" with an exclamation point by definition is yelling. Downvoting is part of the system. Saying that you never downvote any answer is not something to brag about. It means that you aren't using the system the way it was intended. You should read help and meta on why downvoting important.

Comment: This helped solve the problem. The current selenium version uses find_element() to get elements. Thank you